# convert the python list to the dictionary with the same key but with different values

Tags: python, json, list

i want to convert the list data into the json format

list data:

```
list1 = ['coder', 'cats-dogs', 'ic', 'qwerty', 'ash', 'aish', 'ss', 'ssl', 'messi']
```

i expect the output:

```
[ 
 {
  "projectname":"coder"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"cats-dogs"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"ic"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"qwerty"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"ash"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"aish"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"ss"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"sl"
 },
 {
  "projectname":"messi"
 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? do you have a specific question?

Comment: [dict(projectname=item) for item in list1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that you seem to want can be obtained with :

```
[{"projectname" : key} for key in list1]
```

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as solved if you're happy with that.